# if statement doesn't work on Nucleo64 but it does on Maple mini

Tags: c++, arduino, stm32, nucleo

I have a code that works on Maple Mini but I have to change hardware to Nucleo F030r8 because it has more ADC's and it totally sucks. 
In the `modbus_update()` function there is a check of the size of `inputBuffer` and the following code should run only if the value of this variable is bigger than 0.

```
  if (inputBuffer > 0 && micros() - microsFlag >= T3_5) {
  ...
  }
```

But it runs even if value of `inputBuffer` is exactly 0. The strange thing is that this code (with different serial ports opening method) runs perfectly on Maple Mini. Does anyone have any idea what can be be the problem?

Here is the whole code:

```
#define BAUDRATE 19200
#define RE_PIN PC12
#define TE_PIN PF4
#define LED_PIN LED_BUILTIN
#define SLAVE_ID 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256             // max frame size
#define READ_INTERNAL_REGISTERS 4   // function code
#define MIN_REGISTER_ADDRESS 30001
#define MAX_REGISTER_ADDRESS 30020
#define MAX_SENSORS_PER_ROW 10
#define SENSORS_PER_ROW 7
#define MAX_ROWS 2
#define ROWS 1
#define DEBUG true
#define INVALID_VALUE 0x7FFF

const byte INPUTS[] = {PA0, PA1, PA4, PB0, PC1, PC0};
unsigned char frame[BUFFER_SIZE];
unsigned char functionCode;
unsigned int T1;
unsigned int T1_5; // inter character time out
unsigned int T3_5; // frame delay
unsigned long millisFlag = 0;
unsigned long microsFlag = 0;
unsigned char inputBuffer = 0;
int dlyCounter = 0;
int16_t sensorVals[MAX_SENSORS_PER_ROW * MAX_ROWS];
/*
HardwareSerial *modbus = &Serial;
HardwareSerial Serial1(PA10, PA9);
HardwareSerial *debug = &Serial1;
*/
HardwareSerial debug(PA10, PA9);
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  for (int i = 0; i < SENSORS_PER_ROW; i++) {
    pinMode(INPUTS[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
  }
  debug.begin(BAUDRATE, SERIAL_8E1);
  modbus_configure(BAUDRATE, 0); // baud rate, low latency
  microsFlag = micros();
}

void loop() {
  readSensorVals(100);
  modbus_update();
}

unsigned int modbus_update() {
  unsigned char overflow = 0;

  while (Serial.available()) {
    if (overflow) {
      Serial.read(); // empty the input buffer
    } else {
      if (inputBuffer == BUFFER_SIZE) {
        overflow = 1;
      } else {
        frame[inputBuffer] = Serial.read();
        inputBuffer++;
      }
    }
    microsFlag = micros();
  }
  // If an overflow occurred return to the main sketch
  // without responding to the request i.e. force a timeout
  if (overflow) {
    debug.println("Error: input buffer overflow");
    return 0;
  }

  // if inter frame delay occurred, check the incoming package
  if (inputBuffer > 0 && micros() - microsFlag >= T3_5) {
    debug.println("\nIncoming frame:");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputBuffer; i++) {
      debug.print(frame[i], HEX);
      debug.print(" ");
    }
    debug.println();

    // check CRC
    unsigned int crc = ((frame[inputBuffer - 2] << 8) | frame[inputBuffer - 1]); // combine the crc Low & High bytes
    if (calculateCRC(frame, inputBuffer - 2) != crc) {
      debug.println("Error: checksum failed");
      inputBuffer = 0;
      return 0;
    }
    debug.println("CRC OK");

    // check ID
    unsigned char id = frame[0];
    if (id > 242) {
      debug.println("Error: Invalid ID");
      inputBuffer = 0;
      return 0;
    }

    // check if it's a broadcast message
    if (id == 0) {
      debug.println("Broadcast message");
      inputBuffer = 0;
      return 0;
    }

    if (id != SLAVE_ID) {
      debug.println("Not my ID");
      inputBuffer = 0;
      return 0;
    }
    debug.println("ID OK");

    // check function code
    functionCode = frame[1];
    if (functionCode != READ_INTERNAL_REGISTERS) {
      debug.println("Exception: illegal function");
      exceptionResponse(1);
      inputBuffer = 0;
      return 0;
    }
    debug.println("Function code OK");

    // check frame size (function 4 frame MUST be 8 bytes long)
    if (inputBuffer != 8) {
    // some workaround here:
    //if (inputBuffer != 8 || !(inputBuffer == 9 && frame[inputBuffer] == 0)) {
      debug.println("Error: inaccurate frame length");
      inputBuffer = 0;
      return 0;
    }
    debug.println("Frame size OK");

    // check data address range
    unsigned int noOfRegisters = ((frame[4] << 8) | frame[5]); // combine the number of register bytes
    if (noOfRegisters > 125) {
      debug.println("Exception: illegal data address");
      exceptionResponse(2);
      inputBuffer = 0;
      return 0;
    }

    unsigned int firstRegAddress = ((frame[2] << 8) | frame[3]); // combine the starting address bytes
    debug.print("First address: ");
    debug.println(firstRegAddress);

    unsigned int lastRegAddress = firstRegAddress + noOfRegisters - 1;
    debug.print("Last address: ");
    debug.println(lastRegAddress);

    unsigned char noOfBytes = noOfRegisters * 2;
    unsigned char responseFrameSize = 5 + noOfBytes; // ID, functionCode, noOfBytes, (dataLo + dataHi) * number of registers, crcLo, crcHi
    unsigned char responseFrame[responseFrameSize];
    responseFrame[0] = SLAVE_ID;
    responseFrame[1] = 0x04;
    responseFrame[2] = noOfBytes;
    unsigned char address = 3; // PDU starts at the 4th byte
    for (int index = (int)(firstRegAddress - MIN_REGISTER_ADDRESS); index <= (int)(lastRegAddress - MIN_REGISTER_ADDRESS); index++) {
      int16_t temp = (index >= 0 && index < MAX_ROWS * MAX_SENSORS_PER_ROW) ? sensorVals[index] : INVALID_VALUE;
      responseFrame[address] = temp >> 8; // split the register into 2 bytes
      address++;
      responseFrame[address] = temp & 0xFF;
      address++;
    }
    unsigned int crc16 = calculateCRC(responseFrame, responseFrameSize - 2);
    responseFrame[responseFrameSize - 2] = crc16 >> 8; // split crc into 2 bytes
    responseFrame[responseFrameSize - 1] = crc16 & 0xFF;
    debug.println("Frame to send:");
    for (int i = 0; i < responseFrameSize; i++) {
      debug.print(responseFrame[i], HEX);
      debug.print(" ");
    }
    debug.println();
    sendPacket(responseFrame, responseFrameSize);

    inputBuffer = 0;

    while (Serial.available()) { // empty input buffer
      Serial.read();
    }
  }
}

void modbus_configure(long baud, unsigned char _lowLatency) {
  Serial.begin(baud, SERIAL_8E1);
  pinMode(TE_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RE_PIN, OUTPUT);
  rxEnable(); // pin 0 & pin 1 are reserved for RX/TX. To disable set TE and RE pin < 2

  if (baud == 1000000 && _lowLatency) {
    T1 = 1;
    T1_5 = 1;
    T3_5 = 10;
  } else if (baud >= 115200 && _lowLatency) {
    T1 = 50;
    T1_5 = 75;
    T3_5 = 175;
  } else if (baud > 19200) {
    T1 = 500;
    T1_5 = 750;
    T3_5 = 1750;
  } else {
    T1 = 10000000 / baud;
    T1_5 = 15000000 / baud; // 1T * 1.5 = T1.5
    T3_5 = 35000000 / baud; // 1T * 3.5 = T3.5
  }
}

void exceptionResponse(unsigned char exception) {
  unsigned char responseFrameSize = 5;
  unsigned char responseFrame[responseFrameSize];
  responseFrame[0] = SLAVE_ID;
  responseFrame[1] = (functionCode | 0x80); // set the MSB bit high, informs the master of an exception
  responseFrame[2] = exception;
  unsigned int crc16 = calculateCRC(responseFrame, 3); // ID, functionCode + 0x80, exception code == 3 bytes
  responseFrame[3] = crc16 >> 8;
  responseFrame[4] = crc16 & 0xFF;
  sendPacket(responseFrame, responseFrameSize); // exception response is always 5 bytes (ID, functionCode + 0x80, exception code, 2 bytes crc)
}

unsigned int calculateCRC(unsigned char f[], byte bufferSize) {
  unsigned int temp, temp2, flag;
  temp = 0xFFFF;
  for (unsigned char i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)  {
    temp = temp ^ f[i];
    for (unsigned char j = 1; j <= 8; j++)   {
      flag = temp & 0x0001;
      temp >>= 1;
      if (flag)
        temp ^= 0xA001;
    }
  }
  // Reverse byte order.
  temp2 = temp >> 8;
  temp = (temp << 8) | temp2;
  temp &= 0xFFFF;
  return temp; // the returned value is already swapped - crcLo byte is first & crcHi byte is last
}

void rxEnable() {
  if (TE_PIN > 1 && RE_PIN > 1) {
    digitalWrite(TE_PIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RE_PIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  }
}

void txEnable() {
  if (TE_PIN > 1 && RE_PIN > 1) {
    digitalWrite(TE_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RE_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  }
}

void sendPacket(unsigned char f[], unsigned char bufferSize) {
  txEnable();
  delayMicroseconds(T3_5);
  for (unsigned char i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    Serial.write(f[i]);
  }
  Serial.flush();
  delayMicroseconds(T3_5); // allow frame delay to indicate end of transmission
  rxEnable();
}

// @param dly delay between sensor readings in milliseconds
void readSensorVals(int dly) {
  if (millis() != millisFlag) {
    dlyCounter++;
    millisFlag = millis();
  }
  if (dlyCounter >= dly) { // read sensor values
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SENSORS_PER_ROW; j++) {
        int actualIndex = i * MAX_SENSORS_PER_ROW + j;
        if (i < ROWS && j < SENSORS_PER_ROW) {
          sensorVals[actualIndex] = random(20, 30);
          //sensorVals[actualIndex] = (4096 - analogRead(INPUTS[j])) / 20 - 133;
        } else {
          sensorVals[actualIndex] = INVALID_VALUE;
        }
      }
    }
    dlyCounter = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: unsigned overflow? did you try `micros() >= T3_5 +  microsFlag` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not a minimal example. And I'm pretty sure that `if` statements do work.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Overflow on the right-hand side wouldn't matter, because `if (inputBuffer > 0 &&`  should have short-circuited when `inputBuffer==0`.

Comment: Please read about [mcve] and provide one

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide a minimal reproducible example, because if I do so (i.e. comment out everything that belongs to `Serial`, everything starts to work. I guess the problem isn't in the if statement itself, something else producing this malfunction, but I can't find it as the code compiles, amd the whole thing runs on a maple mini without any problem.

Comment: Start by adding parenthesis in your "if" condition properly.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean thanks for your advice but I can't see any problem with parenthesis of the `if` condition. Could you please tell me what should I fix?
(`if ((inputBuffer > 0) && (micros() - microsFlag >= T3_5))` is'nt work either as it should be the same as I wrote originally)

Comment: Could you simply add a debug.print() for the inputbuffer value directly after the if

Comment: @tykhaytschaar it was more a general advice to improve readability and avoid nasty bugs related to operators precedence. There is necessarily something wrong in your analysis.  How do you check that `inputBuffer` is 0 when the if condition is evaluated ? Can you add the disassembly corresponding to the `if` ?